# Looking for 3D Data Visualization Tutorial in QGIS 3.10

Tags: qgis-3, 3d, references

I want to extrude polygons based on a attribute value, and then view this with 3D Map View.

I have been struggling for days and are not getting anywhere. I am using QGIS 3.10.4.

Can someone please refer me to a tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

In the properties of your polygon layer, in "Symbology", choose "2.5D".
"Height" should be the attribute indicating the z value.

I think this [New QGIS and 3D visualisation](https://medium.com/the-pointscene-diaries/3d-map-qgis-guide-4688975b8fb4) tutorial can help you to make what you want.